# can someone explain me the node setup in red and why does the -0.5 value keeps the plane from moving up and down?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I am trying to understand why the value of -0.5 stops the plane from moving vertically and how do

[image: i am trying to understand why the value of -0.5 stops the plane from moving vertically and how do]

Comment: Wherever you got this setup from, either the one who made this had no idea what he did so made it unnecessarily complicated or there was a specific reason to build it like that which should be explained somewhere.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I am following a udemy course for environment creation where this particular node setup is used to create terrain without displacing it from its origin

Comment: Okay, I don't know if this will make sense somewhere in the course, but the result of the whole frame in the middle between the _Color Ramp_ and the _Set Position_ nodes can be achieved much easier and less redundant with one of the setup in the answer by @lemon

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, lemon provided better solutions and were easy to understand as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, it allows to shift Z of a value between -0.59 and 0.59.

---

Noise texture outputs a value between 0 and 1.

Color ramp, as it is, keeps the value between 0 and 1.

The calculation:

Upper part will shift the position in Z between 0 and 1 multiplied by 1.180, so 0 to 1.180.

Lower part half and negates then value of 1.180 and sets it as a second shift for Z.

So the result is a shift on Z position between -1.180 * 0.5 and 1.180 - (1.180 * 0.5) which is from -0.59 to 0.59.

---

That can be also done by:

[image]

As we go from 0 to 1, substract 0.5, so that it is now from -0.5 and 0.5 and multiply by 1.180 to finally have it between -0.59 and 0.59.

Or by:

[image]

which directly remaps from 0 to 1 into -0.59 to 0.59.

---

0.5 comes from this:

[image]

What occurs to 1 above is proportionally the same for 1.180.

Comment: the value of 1.180 can be changed according to our needs but the -0.5 value cannot be changed as the plane will start moving in the z direction and not just the texture. the -0.5 value keeps the plane attached to the origin and only moves the texture How do we come to that value?

Comment: @NishchayGawai The _Noise Texture_ produces pseudo-random values between 0 and 1 (in case of the _Fac_ output single float values, while the _Color_ output has random values between 0 and 1 per each of its RGB channels), which average around 0.5, so the plane is moved upwards 0.5 on average (because X and Y offset are set to 0).

Comment: @NishchayGawai, I have added a figure, in hope that helps to see where 0.5 comes from.

Comment: @lemon: May I ask why do you keep the *Color Ramp* node and not just plug the *Fac* socket of the *Noise Texture* node to the *Map Range Value* socket ? I don't see why adding RGBA single float values is "better" than a single float value.

Comment: @StefLAncien, I think we need to keep things as close possible to the question here, with no other enhancements. And anyway we don't know why the original node setup has been made this way...

Comment: i am new to geometry nodes so map range has been a little hard so i use color ramp so that i can see it visually in viewer node

Comment: @lemon is there any way I can share the file with you?

Comment: you can use this https://blend-exchange.com/ and copy/paste the link you've obtained here.

Comment: @StefLAncien Since the original setup is from a course, it might also be that the _Color Ramp_ is used to later manipulate the interpolation between 0 and 1 other than linear, so I would leave it in there as well.

Comment: @lemon what I understood was that whatever value I put to manipulate the terrain the -0.5 value will always halve the value into the negative direction and positive direction

Comment: Yes, more exactly, in your original node setup, it set the position to the full positive value and offset it back by half of it.

Comment: More exactly by half of the full possible positive value.

Comment: yes, will this setup [the ones provided by you as well] always work for any texture ?

Comment: Well, there is no general case, but yes, you can always apply this calculation to textures: color output are convertible to float between 0 and 1, so you can.